# Performance of a website and MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, networking

I have a PHP page that has some HTML and JavaScript mixed in. The majority of the file is JavaScript. The JavaScript shows some graphics on the screen, asks the user some questions, and records some data. It then inserts that data into a MySQL table.

Suppose I have 1000 people on this webpage at the same time. Suppose they all finish at the same time. Two questions

1. Does having 1000 people versus 1 person slow down the script performance for any given person?
2. Does having 1000 people inserting data into a MySQL table at the
   same time mean that I will lose lots of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, obviously doing 1,000 times the work at once means that there is a very high potential for hurting performance.

No, inserting data into MySQL 1,000 times at once doesn't mean you will lose data.  MySQL takes care of all the concurrency issues when writing to disk.

Comment: See because I thought the script would be downloaded to the computer and then run locally...

Comment: PHP scripts run on the server.  The only thing that is downloaded is the output of that script.

Comment: But what about the javascript that is embedded in my php file?

Comment: That's part of the output of your PHP script and runs client-side.  Anything that runs client-side won't have an impact on other users' performance, provided that it doesn't rely on anything on the server (AJAX requests, etc.)

Comment: Okay so everything embedded in <script type="text/Javascript"> runs client side and won't have an impact on other user's performance?

Comment: That's correct, unless it's relying on server-side resources.

Comment: It relies on images that are stored on the server, however I preload them using an image object at the beginning of the script. What about this?

Comment: If you have 1,000 users loading images from your server all at once, this is a significant load.  If your script cannot proceed until these images are loaded, it will slow things down, certainly.